# Linking to custom memory allocator for c++

Tags: c++, arm, cross-compiling, allocator

I have a goal of cross-compiling some code written in C++ for an ARM processor. There's no OS running on there and we require bare-metal code. However, the issue is that a lot of the C++ code I want to run aren't bare-metal and need at least dynamic memory.

I was hoping to do some sort of basic memory allocator (probably a linear allocator) and link to it such that the C++ code can compile and run without an OS. But I'm not sure what C++11 or the like uses to allocate memory. In C, I'd write a custom malloc and free function. But C++ has so many ways to allocate memory (new pre-C++11, smart pointer create functions, etc.) I'm not sure how to replace memory allocation with my own. I imagine there's some library I have to write that contains allocation functions and then I link to it?

Comment: You can have a look at other custom allocators such as jemalloc. They seem to define their overrides for C++ here: https://github.com/jemalloc/jemalloc/blob/dev/src/jemalloc_cpp.cpp

Comment: I'd probably go with a small RTOS or find an already existing solution such as [this](https://github.com/cortexm/baremetal).

Comment: You need to link to functions your program uses. If you are only using raw `new` and `delete`, you need to provide your own `operator new()` and `operator delete()`. If you use the standard library (smart pointers, containers etc), you need to link to the standard library. (Not all of it is template code in header files). This means you need to port at least those parts of the standard library to your environment. This could be quite an effort.

Comment: Thanks. Let's say I avoid std:: is all object allocation in C++ new and delete? Even though syntactically C++11 doesn't use the new operator?

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you just try? Compile and link some code and it will tell you what symbols are missing.

For memory allocations you have to implement `new`, `new[]`, `delete` and `delete[]`. For baremetal you will also need to implement calling ctors through the `init_array` and if you don't compile without exceptions and RTTI there is a whole bunch of other support stuff you need to implement or link from the freestanding c++ compiler.